# /system/bin/app_process stack corruption detected: aborted ? What is this?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm running some native code, and there are many JNI calls
Application crashes without a clue on why its crashing except for the message /system/bin/app_process stack corruption detected: aborted in logcat if I try to debug

How to go about nailing culprit in this case? Any one ou there who can help here

Comment: add logging in and around calls to your native methods, so you can see what happened just before the crash.

Comment: Add even more detailed logging, in the meantime post your current log.  Are you doing anything unsupported, such as trying to execute a separate process or shell command?

Comment: Nope I haven't done anything unsupported stuff, however if I place CPP FLAG = -fstack-check in adnroid.mk file no crash now, I'm still in dark about this It's actually crashing after a simple constructor like Point::Point()

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert of C/C++, and ran into a similar problem in NDK.(App crash with a log: "/system/bin/app_process stack corruption detected: aborted").

I find out the cause of my error is array access violation.

Just in case someone new like me run into this issue, following are some common mistakes:

1.

```
char  aa[6];
strcpy(aa,"abcdefghijk123457890");//out of bounds
```

2.

```
char aa［6］；
sprintf（aa,“the value is : %d”, 123);//out of bounds
```